# Declaration of formatErrors() should be compatible with FormRequest::formatErrors in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For using [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) in laravel, I created a **StoreCourseRequest** class like this :

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Http\Requests\Request;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class StoreCourseRequest extends Request
    {
        public function authorize ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public function rules ()
        {
            return [
                'title'       => 'required',
                'description' => 'required'
            ];
        }

        public function messages ()
        {
            return [
                'title.required'       => 'عنوان دوره را وارد کنید',
                'description.required' => 'توضیحات دوره را وارد کنید',
            ];
        }


        protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
        {

            $result = ['success' => false, 'msg' => $validator->errors()->first()];

return $result;
            }

        }
```

Because all request sends as Ajax, I want to customize format of error messages as you see in above code.

But after sending request , error below is occurred :

```
ErrorException in StoreCourseRequest.php line 9:
Declaration of App\Http\Requests\StoreCourseRequest::formatErrors() should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest::formatErrors(Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
```

I think that all things is right and follow docs instruction to create formrequest Class but i do not know what is that error and Why occurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the beginning of your file to:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Http\Requests\Request;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
```

As you can see in the error message, `FormRequest::formatErrors()` method requires `$validator` param to be instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator`, but you have imported `use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;`

Comment: Thanks @drndavi,your solution was right, but how can I change returned `Status Code:422 Unprocessable Entity` to `OK 200` in Ajax form requests

Comment: If you get that response, then most likely the data submitted has been caught by the validator as not meeting the requirements, and you'd need to handle that response in your frontend

Comment: I added a response method to StoreCourseRequest class like this : `public function response (array $errors)
  {
   return response()->json($errors, 200);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that your declaration of the method `formatErrors` is incompatible with that of the parent class you are trying to override.

You are aliasing `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` to `Validator`, but the method expects a validator of the type `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator`. Try changing the imported `Validator` class.

Thus, change line ~4 from:

`use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;`

to

`use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;`